# T-test between rows - matching string names

Tags: r

I would like to perform t-test and extract pvalue for all of `Names` in comparison to both `References`. That is how data look like:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Area = c(3.62, 12.14, 13.74, 3.14, 131.86, 
                             7.14, 14.66, 15.38, 12, 13.02, 192.12, 21.54, 13.38, 55.84, 23.86, 
                             5.38, 200.56, 11.06, 12.12, 41.98, 33.32, 6.96, 210.12, 3.56), 
               Names = c("Mark", "Peter", "Greg", "Manuel", "Reference1", 
                         "Reference2", "Mark", "Peter", "Greg", "Manuel", "Reference1", 
                         "Reference2", "Mark", "Peter", "Greg", "Manuel", "Reference1", 
                         "Reference2", "Mark", "Peter", "Greg", "Manuel", "Reference1", 
                         "Reference2")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to take `Area` for 4 replicates of each `Name` (Mark, Peter, Greg, Manuel) and compare it to `Reference1` and `Reference2` areas. How to do that ?

Comment: So, do you want to take the average of `Area` for `Mark`, `Peter`, `Greg` and `Manuel` and compare that average to the average of `Area` for `Reference1` and `Reference2`?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df <- setDT(df)
```

I would first get the list of unique names that are not `Reference`:

```
namelist <- grep("^(?!Reference).*$",df$Names,perl = T,value = T) %>% unique()
```

Then just using `sapply` and the `t.test` function to do a t.test between the name variable and a reference: for `Reference1`:

```
sapply(namelist,function(nom){
  t.test(df[Names == nom,Area],df[Names == "Reference1",Area])$p.value
})

        Mark        Peter         Greg       Manuel 
0.0019808894 0.0007699491 0.0016631637 0.0019262987
```

And for the second reference:

```
sapply(namelist,function(nom){
  t.test(df[Names == nom,Area],df[Names == "Reference2",Area])$p.value
})

     Mark     Peter      Greg    Manuel 
0.9802556 0.1460768 0.1690645 0.4439897
```

I use data.table just for simplicity of subsetting the data.table, but use whatever you like. In base R, you wil do `df$Area[df$Names == nom]` instead of `df[Names == nom,Area]`